# Problema de conexion sqlserver con php

Tags: php, sql, visual-studio

recientemente me surgio este problema con la conexion. El tema es que en mi laptop personal me resulto sin problemas, de hecho hice un grid view de una tabla, pero en este laptop de trabajo me sale este error y tengo el mismo codigo, solo cambie el nombre del pc y la instancia. Agradeceria su ayuda.

Adjunto pantallazo del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el codigo donde haces la conexion a la base de datos? Si muestras el codigo de lo que haz hecho, ayuda a ser mas facil responder a tu pregunta

Comment: `<?php

try {

    $conexion=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=LAPTOP-RTA90HBT\SQLEXPRESS;database=ProyectoPodologia","salud","podologia2022");

} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Ocurrió un error en la conexion. " .$e->getMessage();
}`

En los dos PCs tengo el mismo codigo, lo unico que cambia es el nombre del servidor y la instancia.

Comment: El código va en la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. Como ves, es ilegible en los comentarios